# Change pixel format for drawing into bitmap

Tags: c++, .net, opengl, gdi

I need swap RGBA channel in bitmap pixels. For example .net graphics write channels into bitmap in BGRA and i need RGBA. I think this order determined by PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR, but i don't know how. I do folow

```
 PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = { 
            sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),   // size of this pfd  
            1,                     // version number  
            PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP |   // support window  
            PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | 
            PFD_NEED_PALETTE,       
            PFD_TYPE_COLORINDEX,         // RGBA type  
            32,                    // 24-bit color depth  
            8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0,      // color bits ignored  
            8,                     // no alpha buffer  
            0,                     // shift bit ignored  
            0,                     // no accumulation buffer  
            0, 0, 0, 0,            // accum bits ignored  
            32,                    // 32-bit z-buffer  
            0,                     // no stencil buffer  
            0,                     // no auxiliary buffer  
            PFD_MAIN_PLANE,        // main layer  
            0,                     // reserved  
            0, 0, 0                // layer masks ignored  
        }; 


        int  iPixelFormat; 
  ::SelectObject ((HDC)_hdc.ToPointer (), (HBITMAP)_hBitmap.ToPointer ());

        iPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat((HDC)_hdc.ToPointer (), &pfd); 
    bool result = ::SetPixelFormat((HDC)_hdc.ToPointer (), iPixelFormat, &pfd);
```

I try to change shift of channels, but it is do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using .NET and windows - Take a look at [this](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop3d/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/ImageEx.cs) bit of code from Monogame. It uses a ColorMatrix to transpose color components. This method is fast, reliable and flexible in my experience.

For your particular problem, though it looks like you need a way to convert from RGBA images supplied by VTK to BGRA that Bitmap takes. I see two options here:

1. Ask VTK to render into a BGRA bitmap (some sort of SetPixelFormat call in VTK?)
2. Use a pixel shader that swaps the channels while doing the rendering. This will have hardly any associated cost and it looks like you're using OpenGL anyway.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer. It could helps, if i draw only images into my bitmap, but I draw lines, rectangles etc. According to it I could redraw my bitmap with ColorMap, but it is draw image twice and it is not necessary, cause i may swap my channels directly in memory. I think about something like color map in draw-time.

Comment: Why do you need to transpose bits everytime you draw something? Is it not enough to do this once - either at beginning or at the end? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I use vtk library to visualise this bitmap and vtk use RGBA color scheme of bitmap, instead BGRA that give me Graphics after painting. Now it is directly swap B and R before visualising.